# How can I make these two sentences into one?

Tags: asp-classic

How do I make these two sentences into one?

```
response.Write "<a href=""javascript:;"" onclick=""winBRopen('../share/include/asp_date_picker_calendar-v1.2/cal_popup.asp?FormName=condForm&amp;FieldName=" & mDate & "_Day&amp;FieldName1=" & mDate & "_Day&amp;FieldName2=" & mDate & "_Month&amp;FieldName3=" & mDate & "_Year&amp;Date=" & mDate & "/" & mDate & "/" & mDate & "&amp;CurrentDate=" & Date() & "','popup_cal','241','276','no','no')"">"
response.Write "<td align=left ><img src='..\common_pic\cal.gif' border='0' class=DatePicker alt=Pick A Date /></a></td>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
response.Write "<td align=left ><a href=""javascript:;"" onclick=""winBRopen('../share/include/asp_date_picker_calendar-v1.2/cal_popup.asp?FormName=condForm&amp;FieldName=" & mDate & "_Day&amp;FieldName1=" & mDate & "_Day&amp;FieldName2=" & mDate & "_Month&amp;FieldName3=" & mDate & "_Year&amp;Date=" & mDate & "/" & mDate & "/" & mDate & "&amp;CurrentDate=" & Date() & "','popup_cal','241','276','no','no')""><img src='..\common_pic\cal.gif' border='0' class=DatePicker alt=Pick A Date /></a></td>"
```

By the way it's not well formated, you may try to use a string.Format and create the link(a) into one variable and add it to the rest of the string later on.

Comment: Sadly there is no `string.Format` in asp-classic. There are some libraries that add similar functionality though.

Comment: Having said that, the intent is still valid - concatenate the url into a variable and then use the variable in generating your HTML. Makes it a little easier to modify/troubleshoot.